# Parsing informational assembly version using regular expression

Tags: regex

I'am trying to parse informational version strings using regular expression.

The version string varies in it's appearance

```
// CI Build
2020.2.18-preview.2-b5d95e5992d99f6a6eef8faf71c47df694c763bd

// CI Release Build
2020.2.18-b5d95e5992d99f6a6eef8faf71c47df694c763bd

// Local Build
2020.2.18-preview.0

// Other...
2020.2.18
```

In all cases I'd like to retrieve following parts

```
version = 2020.2.18
suffix = preview.0, preview.2 or empty
hash = b5d95e5992d99f6a6eef8faf71c47df694c763bd or empty
```

The only part that **must** exist is the version part.

My current expression is

```
(?<Version>(?>\d+\.?){3,})(?:-(?<Suffix>.*?))(?:-(?<Hash>[0-9a-f]{5,40}))
```

Any hint on how I can make **suffix** and **hash** optional?

I tried adding a simple zero or one to either of them but that didn't work.

Comment: Try `^(?<Version>(?>\d+\.?){3,})(?:-(?<Suffix>.*?))??(?:-(?<Hash>[0-9a-f]{5,40}))?$`

Comment: That was quick and it worked. Can you post this as answer an possibly explain me what `??` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<Version>(?>\d+\.?){3,})(?:-(?<Suffix>.*?))??(?:-(?<Hash>[0-9a-f]{5,40}))?$
```

Main points:

- `^` matches the start of string and `$`  matches the end of string
- `(?:-(?<Suffix>.*?))??` is an optional lazy patten that matches 0 or 1 times, it is only tried when the next subpatterns do not match
- `(?:-(?<Hash>[0-9a-f]{5,40}))?` is an optional greedy patten, tried 1 or 0 times.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WjKQEt/1).